# How to change XML element value

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I need your help to finish my task also gain some knowledge from it.

I am having XMl like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<spml:batchRequest xmlns:subscriber="urn:abc:names:prov:gw:SUBSCRIBER:3:0" xmlns:spml="urn:abc:names:prov:gw:SPML:2:0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" execution="synchronous" timestamp="true" processing="sequential" onError="exit_commit">
    <version>SUBSCRIBER_v30</version>
    <request xsi:type="spml:ModifyRequest" returnResultingObject="full">
        <version>SUBSCRIBER_v30</version>
        <objectclass>Subscriber</objectclass>
        <identifier>1234567890</identifier>
        <modification name="udm5gData/servingPlmnId[@plmnId='20201']/provisionedData/sessionManagementSubscriptionData[@singleNssai='1-000002']/dnnConfiguration[@dnnId='dj.nmdd']" operation="remove" scope="uniqueTypeMapping" xmlns:subscriber="urn:abc:names:prov:gw:SUBSCRIBER:3:0">
        </modification>
    </request>
</spml:batchRequest>
```

Out of this I need to modify the @singleNssai='**1-000002**' from modification tag Could anyone help me to change.

Something like @singleNssai='**2-000001**'

I am trying like below

```
               XmlDataDocument doc = new XmlDataDocument();
               doc.Load("D:\\soaptemp\\test.xml");

               XmlNode singlenssais = 
               doc.SelectSingleNode("//modification/name/@singleNssai");
                if (singlenssais != null)
                {
                    singlenssais.Value = "2-000001"; // Set to new value.
                }
```

Comment: Modify the value of singleNssai after getting the name element of xml.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication40
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement modification = doc.Descendants("modification").First();
            XAttribute name = modification.Attribute("name");
            string strName = (string)name;
            strName = strName.Replace("1-000002", "2-000001");
            name.SetValue(strName);

        }  
    }
 
}
```